# android listView.setAdapter error with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to to display data from a database table onto a listView by retrieving the data by way of a cursor, passing the cursor to a SimpleCursorAdapter and setting the adapter to a listView, as shown below.
The app crashes due to a problem on listAdapter.setAdapter(adapter).

-I confirmed there is data in the chats table im using

-upon catching the exception, ex.getMessage was null but it indicated the line number as the one with listAdapter.setAdapter(adapter)
CODE:

```
  ChatsActivity.java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Conn connection = new Conn();
    SQLiteDatabase db = connection.getDB(this, "chats", 1);
    //returns readable database

    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM chats", null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.other,
            result,
            new String[]{"_id", "lastContent"},
            new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2});

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setContentView(listView);

    }
}
```

2    Other.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Main"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Sub"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />  </RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_chats.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".ChatsActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  </RelativeLayout>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
setContentView(listView);
```

Instead of passing `listView` to  `setContentView`, pass `Activity_chats.xml` layout id as Activity layout before accessing values from layout:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Activity_chats);
        ....
    }
```